# Difference between query and body in httr::POST

Tags: r, http, post, httr

I want to pass few post parameters in url, say two parameters p1 and p2. Values of p1 and p2 are xyz(string) and 1(numeric). What is difference between following commands:

```
POST(url, body=list(p1="xyz",p2=1))
```

OR

```
POST(url, query=list(p1="xyz",p2=1))
```

I also cannot understand whether I should use quote for parameters p1 and p2 or not. If yes, then which, single or double.

Comment: Quotes for parameters p1 and p2

Comment: Doesn't matter, single or double.

Answer (score 5):

If you're getting started with httr and APIs in general, I would highly recommend that you learn how HTTP requests are structured. One way to do that is empirically, using http://httpbin.org and `verbose()`:

```
library(httr)

args <- list(p1 = "xyz", p2 = 1)

POST("http://httpbin.org/post", query = args, verbose())
#-> POST /post?p1=xyz&p2=1 HTTP/1.1
#-> Host: httpbin.org
#-> Content-Length: 0

POST("http://httpbin.org/post", body = args, verbose())
#-> POST /post HTTP/1.1
#-> Host: httpbin.org
#-> Content-Length: 232
#-> Expect: 100-continue
#-> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---03a3f580d7af2b29
#-> 
#>> ---03a3f580d7af2b29
#>> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="p1"
#>> 
#>> xyz
#>> ---03a3f580d7af2b29
#>> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="p2"
#>> 
#>> 1
#>> ---03a3f580d7af2b29--
```

You'll notice the way that the data is sent is quite different. With `query` the data is encoded in the query part of url, and with `body` its sent in the body of the HTTP request.

Different values of the `encode` argument send the data in different ways:

```
POST("http://httpbin.org/post", body = args, verbose(), encode = "form")
#-> POST /post HTTP/1.1
#-> Host: httpbin.org
#-> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
#-> Content-Length: 11
#-> 
#>> p1=xyz&p2=1

POST("http://httpbin.org/post", body = args, verbose(), encode = "json")
#-> POST /post HTTP/1.1
#-> Host: httpbin.org
#-> Content-Type: application/json
#-> Content-Length: 19
#-> 
#>> {"p1":"xyz","p2":1}
```

(I removed the `User-Agent`, `Accept-Encoding` and `Accept` headers from each example because they're the same in each case, and not germane to the question)

Answer (score 1):

The answer likely depends on what the server is expecting. I would think in many cases, it wouldn't matter; but it would depend on the server.

The second (query) version, is just like calling: `POST(paste0(url, "?p1=xyz&p2=1"))`, whereas the first (body) version passes the parameters as key-value pairs in the body of the HTTP request.

Comment: I think the fact that many servers interpret them the same way isn't relevant - the HTTP requests are quite different